# MMS messages end up in a new conversation with my own phone number as a recipient

Tags: sms, 6.0-marshmallow, mms, nexus-6p

I recently got a Nexus 6P. One very strange and annoying behaviour is that whenever I receive an MMS from someone I have a conversation with the MMS message will be stored in a separate thread with the sender, myself and my phone number (**three participants that is**) as participants. 
And if I answer the with an SMS in that new thread I receive another separate SMS from my own number (because I send the SMS in the group which then goes to the original sender and to my phone number).

So in short, does anyone know why when I receive an MMS that message is separated into a different conversation with me, the original sender and my phone number?

Comment: This seems to be related to the same issue I'm having with Google Messages app (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205036/why-does-google-messages-sms-mms-app-lose-phone-number/)